# PHP,Undefined variable

Tags: php, html

Notice: Undefined variable: rs in /home/sujata/Public/guestbook/edit.php on line 38 (42,46,50)

line 38:

```html
<td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $rs['username'];?>" /></td>
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

edit.php:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf8" />
<title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
define('DEBUG', ture);
if (DEBUG) {
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}
include "conn.php";
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user where id =  ' . $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
if (!empty($_POST['sub'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $refer_url = $_POST['refer_url'];
    $mysql = 'UPDATE user SET username = ' . $username . ', email = ' . $email . ', content = ' . $content . ', refer_url = ' . $refer_url;
    if (mysql_query($mysql)) {
        echo "Edit sucess!";
        header("refresh:5;url = 'admin.php'");
    } else {
        echo "Edit failed.";
    }
}
?>
      <table>
      <form method="post" action="edit.php">
        <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $rs['username'];?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $rs['email'];?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Content:</td>
        <td><textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="5"><?php echo $rs['content'];?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Feedback web address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="refer_url" value="<?php echo $rs['refer_url'];?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

admin.php:

```html
<h1>Admin page</h1>
<?php
include "conn.php";
$sql = "select * from user";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf8" />
    <title>Admin page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <hr />
    <table>
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><?php echo $rs['username'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $rs['id']?>">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="del.php?del=<?php echo $rs['id']?>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Time:</td>
        <td><?php echo $rs['dates'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><?php echo $rs['email'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Content:</td>
        <td><?php echo $rs['content'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Feedback web address:</td>
        <td><?php echo $rs['refer_url'];?></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </table>
  </body>
 </html>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `$rs` if `$_GET['id']` is empty. Are you sure you pass `id` to your script?

In particular, after you submit the form, you use `POST` method, so `$_GET['id']` is certainly unset. You might want to stop the execution of the script before you render the form, if the `$_POST['sub']` was passed in, or pass the user id among other `POST` arguments, and populate `$rs` based on that.

Comment: I have had a test: "echo $rs[1];" added below the line: $rs = mysql_fetch_array($query); I got the value after operating, so I'm sure id was passed. id was passed from below admin.php:

Comment: Do you still see the value after you submit the form?

Comment: No. Just got "Edit failed." and  "Notice: Undefined variable: rs..."error message.

Comment: So at which time do you get the NOTICE? Just when you open it from the admin panel?

Comment: Log in page:http://localhost/guestbook/admin.php, success. Then click "Edit" button, turned to page:
http://localhost/guestbook/edit.php?id=5, no problem, but after I press the "Submit" button in this page, get "Edit failed."info and errors notice.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I said in my answer. When you press the Submit button, it's a POST request, GET[id] is unset, and you never populate the rs. You should either not render the form if POST[sub] was passed in, or propagate the id parameter from the form to the script.

Comment: Make sense. But can not find method to fix, tried a few ways.